# Why doesn't the LogCat tell where the error is in my code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat, android-logcat

I am trying to [use this library](https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable). I am trying to run the demo application given on the github page, but I am getting this exception and the Logcat does not say where the exception is in my code.

**The questions are how to find out where the error is, why do we get this error, and how do I solve this. Ofcourse it all begins by knowing where the error is.**

***My Guess:***

Given in the screenshot is my project structure, according to which the `MainActivity` should have the fully qualified name `br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity`. **BUT** in the error message in the Logcat, it says `Unable to... {br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo/br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity}...` **So may be I have written the wrong name somewhere, like in the manifest or something?** Just in case, I am posting the manifest code as well.

[image]

***LOGCAT:***

```
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583): Process: br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo, PID: 5583
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo/br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:176)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:174)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:92)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onPostResume(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:229)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6089)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
08-21 16:00:05.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5583):     ... 11 more
```

***MANIFEST:***

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <provider android:name=".content_provider.RecentSuggestionsProvider"
                  android:authorities="br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.content_provider.RecentSuggestionsProvider" />

        <provider android:name=".content_provider.CustomSuggestionsProvider"
                  android:authorities="br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.content_provider.CustomSuggestionsProvider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***Note:*** If you think I should post the entire SSCCE code, let me know I'll post it.

---

***EDIT:***

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Activity callbacks __________________________________________________________________________
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        CustomSearchableInfo.setTransparencyColor(Color.parseColor("#ccE3F2FD"));

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    // Handles the intent that carries user's choice in the Search Interface
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            Log.i("Main", "Received query: " + query);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

            assert (bundle != null);

            if (bundle != null) {
                ResultItem receivedItem = bundle.getParcelable(CustomSearchableConstants.CLICKED_RESULT_ITEM);

                Log.i("RI.header", receivedItem.getHeader());
                Log.i("RI.subHeader", receivedItem.getSubHeader());
                Log.i("RI.leftIcon", receivedItem.getLeftIcon().toString());
                Log.i("RI.rightIcon", receivedItem.getRightIcon().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    // Menu callbacks ______________________________________________________________________________
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_a_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            // Calls Custom Searchable Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:text="Custom Search demonstration application"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_a_menu.xml**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="edsilfer.com.br.edsilfer.Main">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"

        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_18dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Looking at my previous projects, the `android:name="MainActivity"` in your manifest should be `android:name="br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity"`.  So yes, use the full package name and see what/if the error is then?  Then I would suggest doing the same with the `provider` names, using the full name including the package and seeing if that works.

Comment: or just put android:name=".MainActivity", because the package is declared before, or as the last comment suggest, but is the same thing.

Comment: Can you post sources for your MainActivity and its corresponding layout file? It appears you are trying to use something that is not a `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones OK lemme try

Comment: @MaxPinto OK lemme try

Comment: @Jeshurun OK in a minute

Comment: if that doesnt work, show the MainActivity code

Comment: @MaxPinto Didn't work `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo/br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference`

Comment: ok, show me your MainActivity code, there should be some error

Comment: @MaxPinto Just added it in the question. Also posted the hyperlink to the library whose demo this is, in the first line in the question. I took the code from there. [Here](https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable) is that library

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Didn't work `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo/br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference`

Comment: ok, i am not sure, but in the onCreate method, try to call the super.Oncreate before apply the theme

Comment: @Jeshurun Just added them. I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable) library. I copied this code from the demo app given there.

Comment: ok, after see that library, look my answer

Comment: @MaxPinto Where is your answer?

Comment: @solace i post my answer right now!

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 3

So, I downloaded the demo project, imported into Android Studio, removed the wrong activity line from the manifest (see in *Edit 2*). Started the project and it works instantly.

Also I just noticed you are using Eclipse. Eclipse is no longer supported and you [*SHOULD*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#section-3) migrate to Android Studio. This could very well be a problem related to this as importing support libs manually might lead to potential errors you have just faced.

To answer your question, **Why doesn't the LogCat tell where the error is in my code**: it actually does tell you, however, the error is in the support lib's source. This is (probably) due to the fact that you are using Eclipse and possibly an incompatible support library or other compiler errors happen, again, because of using the obsolete ADT plugin.

### Edit 2

Something is horribly wrong with that library you want to use. The demo project's manifest contains the following line:

```
<activity  android:name=".ActivityA" android:theme="[...]" />
```

There's no `ActivityA` in the project. I think the problem you've had is also related to the overall status of the project (this a 0.0.6-beta, which means it's extremely unreliable).
I will try to find the error though, just out of curiosity.

### Edit

I see you uploaded the source as well. You might want to remove the `setTheme(...)` from the `onCreate(...)` as it's redundant (you already declared the theme in your manifest).

### Original

First of all, use `android:name=".MainActivity"` instead of `android:name="MainActivity"`. You don't need the FQN (fully qualified name) as the Android VM knows the base package and looks for an activity according to that.

The next issue is around the action bar. I don't see the Activity's source so I'm just making assumptions here based on the error message. You do something in your `onResume()` that causes the `WindowDecorActionBar` to be called on a null action bar. Its `getDecorToolbar(View view)` is trying to figure out the class of the given view. It should be either instance of DecorToolbar or Toolbar. You probably have something else so it goes to the else branch where it throws a `NullPointerException` because the supplied view is indeed null.
I'm not sure what you are trying to do, you might be using wrong classes for, e.g. native Toolbar instead of the support one, or the old ActionBar. Another thing that comes to my mind is you might want to call `super.onResume()` and `super.onCreate()` after you finished initializing your view content. Anyways, without the related parts of the Activity's source I cannot say anything for sure.

The source of [WindowDecorActionBar is here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/WindowDecorActionBar.java).

Answer (score 1):

ok, i do not know your xml (layouts, menu's) code, but check if your menu is like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".BlockActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/search"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_search"
    />
</menu>
```

you should use android support widget in the searchView,
So try and check if you have your layout and menu right way, if not, write your layout code too, because your Activity should work as well.

Regards.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use support widget when the minimum API level is 22

Comment: i am not sure, but if you define in your app theme :android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", you should use in your xml that validations and restrictions too, i suppose

Comment: well, if it is only for api level 22 and up, so theme should be: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" as android manifest from sample has